# 350 mA RGB LED driver IC

Tags: power, led, current, driver, led-driver

I need an inexpensive RGB LED driver IC with minimal BOM that:

```
Can source or sink at least 3 * 350 mA
Has an I2C or SPI or digital interface
Has at least 16384 grayscale intensities
```

Can anyone recommend some devices to consider?
Is it possible to get 14-16 bits for a single 350 mA LED?

I found the TLC5955, which has 65536 brightness adjustment steps, costs about $9.10/piece and it has inconveniently located 48 pins to combine them and connect a RGB LED. RGB LED If: 350/350/350 mA, Vf: 2.1/3.4/3.2, power is one cell Li-Ion 3.7 V.

Comment: That package is really not hard to hand-solder with a bit of practice (and some flux) (and maybe a bit of solder-wick)

Comment: But I'd be looking for a driver with an I2C or SPI interface, as they only need a couple of connections.

Comment: @SiHa, Maybe you're right, I didn't solder such small legs. The digital interface is of little importance to me. Maybe there is an IC with fewer legs, specifically for 1 LED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 13-bit PWM LED Driver option. This is less than I need, but it seems that there are no other options yet.
[Control Color of LED Stage and Architectural Lighting: Easy, Accurate 13-Bit Color using High Power 4 × 1A RGBW LEDs, I2C Control](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/control-color-of-led-stage-and-architectural-lighting-easy-accurate-13-bit-color.html)